# Why is using a local HTTP proxy faster than direct connections?

Tags: networking, proxy, http

I have software on my Windows 11 PC that issues a large amount of HTTP requests to fetch smaller chunks of data (typically < 1MB).
If I instruct the software to use a locally running HTTP proxy (tinyproxy) I can pull high speeds (20MB/s) but if I don't I get really low speeds (600 KB/s).

Tinyproxy runs on linux.
Internet connection is fiber 1000mbps up/down.

I've tried looking at wireshark captures of both but the only difference I see (other than HTTP proxy headers) is that there are a significant number of retries/dupacks with the direct connection.

Browser download sites like speedtest show a decent speed.

This also happens on my PS4 where downloading an update is much slower if I don't use the local proxy.

My Windows PC TCP global parameters look alright

```
    TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State          : enabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : normal
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : default
ECN Capability                      : disabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : allowed
Initial RTO                         : 1000
Receive Segment Coalescing State    : enabled
Non Sack Rtt Resiliency             : disabled
Max SYN Retransmissions             : 4
Fast Open                           : enabled
Fast Open Fallback                  : enabled
HyStart                             : enabled
Proportional Rate Reduction         : enabled
Pacing Profile                      : off
```

Any thoughts how I can debug this further?

Comment: The Linux network evidently uses different settings than Windows. Try to (1) Disable Receive Side Scaling, (2) Disable network adapter offload features.

Comment: Tried both these and there is no change.

Comment: Which proxy server are you using with Tinyproxy?

Comment: @harrymc I don't understand - Tinyproxy is the proxy server. so <Windows PC> -> <TinyProxy on local linux VM> -> <Internet host>

Comment: Does Tinyproxy just connect to your ISP, just the same as the host?

Comment: Yes TinyProxy just makes the request to the internet host (in this case a CDN). This request would get routed via local router, ISP routers, etc.

Comment: "Designed from the ground up to be fast and yet small" is apparently true,